# Headers with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to compilate my own library with the Android NDK But I've got some problems.

Here is my Android.mk file:

```
# Define vars for library that will be build statically.
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE     := MyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := ../../../src/mylib/utils/Timer.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../../src/mylib/

# Optional compiler flags.
LOCAL_LDLIBS     = -lz -lm
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog  
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++0x

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I build my project with "ndk-build" I've got the following error :

```
Clean: mylib [armeabi]
Clean: stlport_shared [armeabi]
Clean: stlport_static [armeabi]
Compile++ thumb  : mylib <= Timer.cpp
jni/../../../src/mylib/utils/Timer.cpp:1:34: fatal error: mylib/utils/Timer.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

For information, I'm including the .hpp like that :

```
#include <mylib/utils/Timer.hpp>
```

I don't know why headers aren't found, my library working in Xcode and eclipse.
Thanks for your time!

Edit: Here is my project's architecture to understand my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrcAC.jpg
I'm trying to indicate where is located my ".hpp" files in the Android.mk file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your LOCAL_C_INCLUDES should include the `../../../src/` or `../../../inc` directory in order for you to use `#include <mylib/utils/Timer.hpp>` i.e:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../../src/
```

Why don't you put your C and C++ headers and source files inside the jni/ directory of the Android project, near the Android.mk file?

See: [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21593/313113)

Also this is incorrect, because the second LOCAL_LDLIBS overrides the previous LOCAL_LDLIBS directive in the current module  :

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS     = -lz -lm
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
```

If you want to append to a make directive use:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lz -lm
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog
```

or `LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lz -lm -llog`

EDIT: 
Using the following Android.mk it seems to work **if you run ndk-build from the Android/jni directory.**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# first lib, which will be built statically
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE     := MyLib
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../../inc/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := ../../../src/mylib/utils/Timer.cpp
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# second lib, which will depend on and include the first one
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyNativeFinalSharedLib
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lz -lm -llog  
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -std=c++0x
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := MyLib   
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Also you forgot to put LOCAL_PATH := (call my-dir) on the first line and some other missing make directives.

> An Android.mk file must begin with the definition of the LOCAL_PATH
>   variable. It is used to locate source files in the development tree.
>   In this example, the macro function 'my-dir', provided by the build
>   system, is used to return the path of the current directory (i.e. the
>   directory containing the Android.mk file itself).

(from android-ndk-r8d/docs/ANDROID-MK.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the line 
`code`LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../../src/`code` didn't work, I've got the following error: "Unsupported source file extensions".

I don't put my .cpp and .hpp files in the same folder or JNI for the architecture clarity, take a look on libraries like SFML who did this too :). In my projects, I'm including the current project in the header search path, so I can include files without searching in subfolders, I can include a "module" too like that "#include <Framework/graphic/graphic.hpp>

Here is my project architecture : [link]http://i.imgur.com/ln3ia9F.jpg

Comment: In that case have you tried `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../../inc`? Also where is your Android.mk file located?  Is it inside the Android/jni ? Where are you running **ndk-build** from? Your sources should go to LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../../src/source1.cpp ../../../source2.cpp Also I suggest that you compile your external code to a shared or static library and then you add a new module for it in the Android.mk file or create a separate file for your library and call it from the main Android.mk inside Android/jni/ directory.

Comment: Yes i've tried too :/.
Android.mk is inside the jni folder yes, here is another picture with more details [link]http://i.imgur.com/aiah6zH.jpg

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot to find the problem! Now I have to deal with #include <unordered_map> during the compilation ^^'.

Comment: Also check this related discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-ndk/VWxNghRtBjY/discussion For using the C++ standard library you need to add the Application.mk file in Android/jni which contains something like: `APP_OPTIM := debug APP_PLATFORM := android-14 APP_STL := gnustl_static APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a` Also make sure you're using the latest Android SDK: android-ndk-r8d Read: android-ndk-r8d/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html and check the android-ndk-r8d/samples directory for various examples using the NDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly recommended to have your `Android.mk` file define `$(LOCAL_PATH)`. In your case, the best choice would probably be

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../../../../src
```

Now you can simply write

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := mylib/utils/Timer.cpp
```

But for the includes, the path should be defined as relative from *current*, i.e. `MyProject/build/Android` directory. In your case, it seems, the correct path would be

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../../../inc
```

This when you specify `mylib` in the `#include` statement:

```
#include <mylib/utils/Timer.hpp>
```

Comment: **bold**the path should be defined as relative from current, i.e. MyProject/build/Android directory.**bold**
That was one of the main problem, thanks a lot! (I had another problem with a bad include in one of my .cpp files, Xcode doesn't say anything strangely.